# Menu 'Swinging' Weirdly when hovered

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm working on a site and I have a big css problem; my menus are 'Swinging' in a very weird manner when hovered. The css /  html code on its own works well, but once I implement the slider within the real site it behaves differently. Its probably a css issue, but also to note is my site is built on a Responsive theme. Anyone with an idea of how I can fix this please lete kme know. Thanks. Here is the [link to the site](http://blanketsandwine.com/).

Comment: Too much code there to wade through but it looks like you need to set the width if your nav li back to what they were before the hover maybe using onmouseout event.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "swinging" do you mean the effect where they start at the top-left then grow diagonally to the bottom-right? That's jQuery's ".show" event firing. Try replacing that with ".slideToggle".

Unfortunately the Wordpress template you're using is quite messy so it's hard to troubleshoot.